# Convert Composite C1 - insert MVC partial requires Visual Studio solution?

Tags: c1-cms

It appears that you either start a Composite C1 site by using the Visual Studio solution - or just install the exe, which contains no solution file and can just be used through the web CMS.

I need to include an MVC 4 Partial in a page on a site that was only installed with the .exe & edited only through the web CMS. Can I add a partial in the CMS (not in VS), or do I have to use VS & manually compile the site before deployment?

I have tried adding the sample MVC files from the below to my C1 site & navigating to /Home:
http://docs.composite.net/Functions/MVC/HelloWorldMVC

The URL for Composite is localhost/mysite

I try going to localhost/mysite/home - but it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you by chance have a C1 page called "Home" and a view called "Home"? They might conflict.

Comment: Also, do check if you really need a MVC 4 Partial page. You can get almost the same with a Razor function. Razor functions are alot easier maintainable than the hole MVC idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do I have to use VS & manually compile the site before deployment?

Normally, you don't need Visual Studio in order to use the MVC Player - unless you have to use VS (or any other tool) to create and add views and controllers to the website. In any case, everything should work on-the-fly without having to compile the website